# SAS - Proc Means and Granularity of Search

Tags: syntax, statistics, sas

I am new to SAS would like my searches to be a more granular.

In this example, I would like my output to show the variable SalesPrice and only those with CentralAir (another variable). I would like to show the statistics for another variable. In this case I want to view the OverallQal variable only if the variable is over 7 and the observations have '1FAM' as its BldgType (which is another variable).

I understand my syntax is incorrect. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
proc means data=MYDATA.AMES_HOUSING_DATA n nmiss p1 p10 q1 mean q3 p90 stddev median;
var SalePrice if (CentralAir = 'Y');
var OverallQual if (OverallQual GT 7 AND BldgType = '1FAM');
run;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Are you trying to summarize a variable but filter it first?  If so, look into WHERE. It would help if you posted some sample data and expected output with your questions.

Comment: FYI The first SAS programming course is available for free as an ecourse from SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` statement (or the `WHERE=` dataset option) to limit the records that the proc uses. You can only use one WHERE clause per procedure though, so you would need to run it twice to select the two different sets of records.  You also might want to use `PROC UNIVARIATE` to get a summary of your variables' distribution.

```
proc univariate data=MYDATA.AMES_HOUSING_DATA ;
  where CentralAir = 'Y';
  var SalePrice;
run;
proc univariate data=MYDATA.AMES_HOUSING_DATA ;
  where OverallQual GT 7 AND BldgType = '1FAM' ;
  var OverallQual ;
run;
```